# Pandas: explode array elements and group?

Tags: pandas

I'm working in Pandas 0.23, and I have an array column and a boolean column. I'd like to group by the boolean and each individual element in the array, to find the counts that are true and false for each element.

Example data:

```
a = pd.DataFrame([
  {'vals': ['a,b,c'], 'succeeded': True},
  {'vals': ['a,b'], 'succeeded': False},
  {'vals': ['c'], 'succeeded': True},
  {'vals': ['b,d'], 'succeeded': False},
])
```

Desired output:

```
      succeeded_t     succeeded_f
a     1               1
b     1               2
c     2               0
d     0               1
```

What's the best way to do this? Do I need to "explode" out the array elements into rows first, then group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to flatten your list then using `crosstab`, also your list is not list , it is one item list with string , you need split it firstly

```
a.vals=a.vals.map(lambda x : x[0].split(','))
newdf=pd.DataFrame({'succeeded':a['succeeded'].reindex(a.index.repeat(a.vals.str.len())),
                    'vals':np.concatenate(a['vals'].values)})
pd.crosstab(newdf['vals'],newdf['succeeded'])
Out[457]: 
succeeded  False  True 
vals                   
a              1      1
b              2      1
c              0      2
d              1      0
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can do this with one go, but just subset to the two groups and use `str.get_dummies` on each subset, then concatenate the results

```
import pandas as pd

pd.concat([a[a.succeeded].vals.str.get_dummies(sep=',').sum().to_frame('succeeded_t'),
           a[~a.succeeded].vals.str.get_dummies(sep=',').sum().to_frame('succeeded_f')], 
          axis=1, sort=True).fillna(0)
```

#### Output:

```
   succeeded_t  succeeded_f
a          1.0          1.0
b          1.0          2.0
c          2.0          0.0
d          0.0          1.0
```

#### Alternatively

If you will have many columns in the output that you don't want to manually concatenate:

```
(a.set_index('succeeded')
  .vals.str.get_dummies(sep=',')
  .groupby(level=0).sum().T
  .rename_axis(None, axis=1))
```

Output:

```
   False  True 
a      1      1
b      2      1
c      0      2
d      1      0
```